# Limit without L'Hopital's rule: $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x\sin2x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I solve the following problem without the use of the L'Hopitals's rule?

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x\sin{(2x)}}$$

Comment: Can use lim(sinx/x) = 1 as x tends to zero?

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto0%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Ccos%5E3%20x%7D%7Bx%5Csin2x%7D%24&p=1) you can find some other posts about the same limit: [Trigonometric simplification for limits: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x\sin2x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888081) or [Why does the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x\sin 2x}$ exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108721)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have that $1-\cos^3x = (1-\cos x)(1+\cos x + \cos^2 x)$ and $x\sin 2x = 2x\sin x \cos x$, so by limit arithmetic
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^3x}{x\sin 2x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x + \cos^2 x)}{2x\sin x \cos x} = \frac{3}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x\sin x}$$
From here, see if you can get a numerator in terms of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Factor $1-\cos^3 x$ and note that $1-\cos x=2\sin^2(x/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $-\frac{(\cos(x)-1)(\cos(x)^2+\cos(x)+1)}{2x\sin(x)\cos(x)}=-\frac{(\cos(x)^2-1)(\cos(x)^2+\cos(x)+1)}{2x\sin(x)\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}=\frac{(\sin(x)(\cos(x)^2+\cos(x)+1)}{2x\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}$ and the searched limit is $\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x\sin(2x)}=\frac{(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))}{2x\sin(x)\cos(x)}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)(1+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))}{4x\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)\cos(x)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\frac{1+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\cos(x/2)\cos(x)}$$

The limit is 3/4.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x\sin 2x}= \frac{1-(1-3x^2/2+O(x^4))}{2x^2-O(x^4)}=\frac{3x^2/2+O(x^4)}{2x^2+O(x^4)}=\frac 34$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: remember the two basic limits
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and rewrite your limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\frac{2x}{\sin2x}(1+\cos x+\cos^2x)
$$

Comment: The second one is not $1/2$. It is $0$.

Comment: @Jack Right. I forgot a two!